# Flutter Sizing Containers()

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Red colored container is a square at all times, ideally has a width 25% and height of 25% but never exceeds a width of 200 or a height of 200.

Amber colored container always matches height of red colored container and fills up spare remaining screen width.

The above criteria can be achieved with the below code. Can anyone achieve this same effect/criteria without using media query for specifying heights and widths ?

```
Scaffold(
        body: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
      Column(children: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0, maxWidth: 200.0),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ]),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0),
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
      ),
    ]));
```

Comment: The use-case requires ```MediaQuery``` as we are considering percentages. Please share the code if yu=ou succeed to achieve the above without using ```MediaQuery```,

Comment: I had tried to achieve the criteria using widgets FractionallySizedBox(widthFactor: 0.25) widget or Expanded(flex 1/3), but was unable to achieve the criteria.

Comment: Maybe use ```get``` package? ```Get.width``` its immutable value

Comment: Get package is just using media query under the hood I believe